# Automate calling predict function

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, prediction

I have an question regarding storing my prediction functions based on what they are predicting so I can later call them in a loop. Below I have attached some sample code that trains different models and then renames those models based on what they are predicting. What I would like to do is be able to call those prediction models in a loop later.

```
library(Cubist)
library(e1071)

data(mtcars)

`%ni%`<-Negate(`%in%`)

dep_vars<-c('mpg','cyl') 
for(dep_var in dep_vars) {

    in_vars<-names(mtcars)[names(mtcars) %ni% dep_var]

    x<-mtcars[,in_vars]

    model1 <- cubist(x = x, y = mtcars[,dep_var], committees = 20,neighbors=2)

    fm <- as.formula(paste(dep_var," ~", paste(in_vars, collapse = "+")))

    model2 <- svm(fm, data = mtcars,  cross = 10)

    assign(paste0('model1_',dep_var),model1)

    assign(paste0('model2_',dep_var),model2)

}
```

## This is the part I could use assistance with

```
for(dep_var in dep_vars) {
    pred1 <- predict(model1, newdata=predict_data) # rather than model1 i need it to be model1_dep_var

    pred2 <- predict(model2, newdata=predict_data) # same here
}
```

Comment: You can store assigned model names as strings in a list or vector and use them in your prediction for loop. e.g. `assign("somename", LETTERS); myvars <- "somename"; get(myvars)`

Comment: I believe this works my friend. Much thanks for the assist!